# Receiving a HEX number and turning into an INT or STRING

Tags: delphi, hex, atmega, delphi-6

I'm sending data from an ATmega in the form of 16 bit (2 bytes). I have a serial component in Delphi which receives the data.

- If I send a String (e.g. `'FF'`), I get the data added to my Memo component. All fine.
- However, if I send the raw hex `$FF`, I get a receive data blink saying "data received" but nothing is added to the Memo component's lines. I'm not sure how to convert this data into an Integer or String, something I can use.

A solution would be good but an explanation on how Delphi sees `String`, `Char`, etc. would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: I presume you mean 8 bit bytes?

Comment: You should show the code which you use to receive data. We need to know the receive buffer data type to give you the best answer. Is it an array of byte or other data type? Also we need to know which Delphi version you use. Old Delphi (Up to Delphi 2007) use 8 bit characters and all recent (Starting from Delphi 2009) use 16 bit characters (Unicode) but also support AnsiChar (8 bit characters) and AnsiString data types.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive data, you can cast them to bytes (if needed) and tranform into hex representation.

For example, if you get `AnsiString`:

```
  AnsiS := Comport.ReadAnsiString; //your reading here
  for i := 1 to Length(AnsiS) do
     Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToHex(Ord(AnsiS[i]), 2));
```

Comment: Thanks. This should work but I have had another thought on sending hex. I cant send data separation characters with this method. Sending strings from the c code may be better option.

Answer (score 1):

When your ATMega sends the string "FF", it sends two characters ("F" and "F"), each encoded to their ASCII code  decimal 70. When your Delphi program receives these two bytes (d70 and d70) it converts those ASCII codes to characters "F" and "F" and adds them to the memo.

When your ATMega sends the hex value FF ($FF as they are represented in Delphi code), it sends one byte with decimal value 255. When your Delphi program receives this one byte (d255) it attempts to convert it to a character but doesn't find a printable character representation for this code. Therefore nothing is added to the memo. Or, maybe your receiving code is filtering out this and possibly other values too.

It's not clear exactly what kind of solution you are looking for, but you can convert the byte value (d255) to hex or decimal representation with `function IntToHex(Value: Integer; Digits: Integer): string;` or `System.SysUtils.Format(const Format: string; const Args: array of const): string;` or use it as a byte value in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to sort this comm thing out and this is what I have come up with after some thought.. A 16 bit number, eg TCNT1 is 2 bytes. This is the shortest way to send the number. Delphi has to do some conversion to get the number into a usable format. This method can only send .hex numbers so there is no option to send other characters as data separators. If I turn TCNT1 into a string, I end up sending 4 bytes. Still quite short and I can now send special data character separators between the numbers. Quite easy to turn a 2 byte hex number into a 4 byte string in c.

Comment: Delphi can read any kind of data from the serial port. It is the task of your Delphi program to correctly decode and use the data from the serial port in an appropriate way. If you are sending binary data (e.g. a 16 bit counter value) from the ATMega, don't convert it to string, but send it as 2 bytes. When receiving, don't attempt to feed the received bytes to a memo without first converting to either decimal or hex representation of the value the 2 bytes represent. If you don't need to show the 2 byte value in a memo, just keep it in a word or integer variable for later use.

Comment: If you need to include separators and/or other markers between packets, then you need to consider some existing protocols or create your own.

Comment: In the mean time, I'm using  the itoa function. However any integer above 32768 returns a -ve figure subtracted from 65536. I have, char buffer[10]; char* itoa(unsigned int, char* , int); then itoa(60000, buffer, 10); send_str(buffer); and I get -5536. Looks like itoa is signed.  The web says it should not be.